# How to compile a sass file with the rest of the html code?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am building a website with HTML and CSS and I must also use an SCSS file, but when I try to update the page the elements defined in the SCSS file are not read. I would like to know how to compile a sass file with the rest of the program.
When i insert a style file i put this in html:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

With SCSS what should I put?

Comment: "With SCSS what should I put?" — The same. The SASS compiller will output regular CSS. (You just need to run the SASS compiler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing SASS on

- Windows: `npm install -g sass` in your VS-Code Terminal OR `choco install sass`
- macOS or Linux: `brew install sass/sass/sass`

Then try `sass .\folder\example.scss .\folder\example.css` to compile your SCSS file.

Or try `sass --watch .\folder\example.scss .\folder\example.css` to compile the SCSS File live.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run `sass --watch example.scss style.css` in the terminal on same folder where your SCSS file. It will compile your SCSS code into CSS.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.  It gives me problems installing the Sass

Comment: What exactly you got error to install sass?